# Loop through structure entry types and matrix blocks

Tags: matrix, structure

Single page website. Navigation based on a Structure section (anchor links). Entries depend on entryTypes.

```
{# set each section ID with for anchor navigation #}
{% for page in craft.entries.section('pages') %}
<section id ="{{ page.slug }}">

    {# check the slug to get the Matrix entries related to the (html) section ID #}
    {% if page.slug == 'home' %}
        {# get the entries for the entry.type #}
        {% set entries = craft.entries.type('pagesHome') %}
            {# loop through the block types and entries #}
            {% for block in page.matrixFieldHandle.type('matrixBlockHandle') %}
                {{ block.title }}
            {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    {# and so on.... #}
    {% if page.slug == 'about' %}
        ......
    {% endif %}

</section>
{% endfor %}
```

Questions: am I setting up this single page website in a too complicated way with too many DB queries? 
Thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

If I was building a single page website I might create a matrix field with different blocks for each "page".

```
{# Navigation #}
{% for block in entry.contentBlock %}
   <li><a href="#{{ block.slug }}">{{ block.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}

{# Content #}
{% for block in entry.contentBlock %}
   <section id="{{ block.slug }}">
     {{ block.body }}
   </section>
{% endfor %}
```

This will allow someone to re-order "pages" easily under one entry. You can also create several different block types with different fields in if these "pages" needed to be different.